# Android Hash Key - it really should be simpler than this

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm trying to create a hash key for Facebook for an app.

I'm on 64 bit Windows Vista.

I have installed Java JDK and OpenSSL (versions openssl-0.9.8e X64 & openssl-0.9.8k X64) and am trying the following:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

And what I get is this:

[image: CMD]

Is there a better way to do this? I am novice at this I suppose but not in general, this is a minefield

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the better way but I followed these steps to get `Keyhash`

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\VivekWa
rde.android\debug.keystore
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Aug 12, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 6fccf69b
Valid from: Mon Aug 12 18:15:22 IST 2013 until: Wed Aug 05 18:15:22 IST 2043
Certificate fingerprints:

MD5:  12:5E:CB:88:01:1D:FB:94:36:84:8B:50:F5:5B:61:DC

SHA1: 5A:60:85:BE:AA:29:3C:18:D5:29:4A:C6:C4:23:DE:89:A6:EA:C2:C8

SHA256: 60:1C:6F:A0:E7:BD:57:F8:02:38:6F:A5:77:7A:57:AC:74:9A:42:3B:6A:
A1:3A:AF:27:38:F1:57:EF:BD:BC:CC

Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Version: 3

Extensions:

//#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 65 5C 20 02 31 12 B8 0B   62 10 77 99 DB C7 D3 76  e\ .1...b.w....v
0010: A5 40 1C 40                                        .@.@
]
]

---

---

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
-keystore "C:\Users\VivekWarde.android" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary
 |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
A5EP+MbXYyEPDcmKBGmZxVJd0oo=

Comment: Thother way you posted is correct... I had to go to Eclipse Window > Preferences > Android > Build and click apply then the debug.keystore file was created...Then run this from CMD... but where is the file now it's created? How do i access it to put the data in Facebook?